# dynamically created labels overlap each other

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I want to create labels that will follow one another. I have a grid name `WordTemplateLayout` to which I want to add the labels. I add them dynamically on the wpf window constructor after `InitializeComponent()` is called. Here is the method creating the labels:

```cs
private void CreateWordTemplate()
        {
            IList<char> template = CurrentGame.Template;
            double widthPerBox = WordTemplateLayout.Width / template.Count;
            //template.Count being a number, irrelevant to the question 
            for (int i = 0; i < template.Count; i++)
            {
                var templateVisual = new Label();
                templateVisual.Name = "c" +  i;
                templateVisual.Width = widthPerBox;
                templateVisual.Height = WordTemplateLayout.Height;
                templateVisual.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
                WordTemplateLayout.Children.Add(templateVisual);
            }
        }
```

the problem being, that what actually appends is that instead of the labels lining up one after the other, they overlap each other:
[The aqua box is all the labels overlap each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xreQ0.png)

so what I am asking, is how can I make the labels line up (horizontally) instead of to overlap?

Comment: I'm certainly not a WPF wiz, but shouldn't you be adding them to a [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=netcore-3.1) or something?

Comment: You could Template these out from an itemscontrol, binding an observablecollection of item viewmodels containing the data for whatever these represent. Adding these in code is a bad plan.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're better off using a StackPanel, or learning how to use viewmodels and data binding. Having said that, to answer your direct question, here's how you'd do it programmatically.

**NOTE: Ignore the `5` that I'm passing in to the methods, and instead use your `template.Count`.  This is was just for me to get it to work on my end.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateGridLayout(5);
            CreateWordTemplate(5);
        }

        // Define the Grid layout
        // If you want the labels to follow one another horizontally, define columns.  
        // If you want them stacked vertically, instead define rows.
        private void CreateGridLayout(int count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                WordTemplateLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            }
        }

        private void CreateWordTemplate(int count)
        {
            double widthPerBox = WordTemplateLayout.Width / 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var templateVisual = new Label();
                templateVisual.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i); // SET YOUR COLUMN HERE!
                templateVisual.Name = "c" + i;
                templateVisual.Width = widthPerBox;
                templateVisual.Height = WordTemplateLayout.Height;
                templateVisual.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
                templateVisual.Content = templateVisual.Name;                
                WordTemplateLayout.Children.Add(templateVisual);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to use another layout so the new elements will get in normal order. try stackPanel.
2. you can use grid and give each new label Row=index.
3. you can give each new label margin, like newLabel.margin-top = index*50